# Matplotlib padding between plot and axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to do a matplolib figure with some padding between the axis and the actual plot.

Here is my example code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.sin(4 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.grid(True)


plt.show()
```

And here is what I am trying to get :

[image: plot with x and y shift]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your case, it's easiest to use `ax.margins(some_percentage)` or equivalently `plt.margins(some_percentage)`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.sin(4 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)

ax.plot(x, y, 'r')
ax.grid(True)
ax.margins(0.05) # 5% padding in all directions

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note the margins setting applies to autoscale; if this has been turned off, it needs to be re-enabled for margins to have an effect: `ax.autoscale(True)`

Answer (score 0):

you can set the limits of the plot with xlim and ylim.
See [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html)